# There are 10.000 leaves stuck in infinitely looping itemduct network. How do I get them out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Yesterday my local server suddenly got huge tick lag. Whenever I place or remove a block, try to open an inventory, eat, etc I need to wait a couple of seconds before the server catches up.

By now, I've finally found the problem. There is a part of my itemduct network that has about 10.000 leaves in an infinite loop, and I don't know how to get them out without crashing Minecraft.

I initially tried breaking a block in the loop, this caused all leaves to spill out and left me with less than 1 FPS. I had to stop it because it just kept getting slower.

Second thing I tried was attaching an inventory to the network and setting a connected itemduct to vacuum. Didn't work, the leaves are still in the network.

Right now, I don't know what else to do. How do I get them out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach a void pipe or void chest to the network, eventually they will be purged, if your fast enough you can also attach a diamond pipe to filter them into the void pipe\chest.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but suddenly all leaves spilled out, out of nowhere (didn't break any blocks). I was lucky enough to have them fall over the edge into the void, and the problem seems fixed now. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If attaching an inventory to the pipes is failing, but breaking the pipes 'works' despite the lag, then create a method to handle the items after they fall out... a hole to the void, a hungry chest, a hopper to a void pipe, etc.